# Xcode : use UIImageView

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiimageview

I have an application that gives wallpapers , but they are given on the whole view.  I put buttons in the interface with actions and when i debug the app. I don't see the buttons, I only see the wallpapers ... But the buttons are working when I press on them while I don't see them on the simulator.  Any idea why ? I'd like to ask how I have to make the pictures coming in a UIImageView wich is now not in the app.  So I'd like to make a app with wallpapers given in a UIIamgeView with a toolbar down for buttons.  And the wallpaper has to be the good size because the user can choose to save the wallpaper in his photos.  ANy idea how to do ?

Currently code using for whole view :

```
-(void)awakeFromNib {

    self.n = 1;
    UIImage* wallpaper = [UIImage imageNamed:@"wp_1.png"];
    UIImageView* view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,420)];
    self.wallpaper = view;
    view.image=wallpaper;
    [self.view addSubview:view];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only see the wallpaper because `addSubview:` inserts the new view on top of all other views. You could use `[self.view insertSubview:view atIndex:0]` to insert it at the bottom, or you could use `[self.view sendSubviewToBack:view]` after adding it to send it to the back.